# C#, For Loop Inside Parallel For Loop Not Working Correctly

Tags: c#, for-loop, webforms, parallel.for

This is my code, and not working correctly.

Normal for loop from 0 to UrlList Count. Maybe 1500 - 2000;

After Every 10 loop, controlling session. If not exists or timeout, going and refresh. And This point first parallel loop working correctly. 
i = 10 and x = between 0 and 9.

And Later, parallel for not working. I'm watching with "add watch" for x.
x is not changing. The last number in the first loop remains what it is.

What can I do?

```
TokenController control = new TokenController();
for (int i = 0; i < UrlList.Count; i++)
{
    if(control.SessionControl(false, 0))
    {
       Parallel.For(i, 10, x => {
          //HttpRequest

       });

       i += 9;
    }
}
```

Comment: `Parallel.For(i, i + 10, x => {...}`? When you at `i`-th postion you want `10` loop *more*, not *from* `i` up to `10`

Comment: @DmitryBychenko off topic but do you have compiler fit in your brain?

Comment: @Lucifer: typical error at typical place: when `loop` *doesn't execute* look at the  conditions (range in the context)

Comment: @Lucifer It is called experience when carrying tens of thousands reputation over here. The main benefit SO has given me is the very quick analysis of what is wrong with a piece of code by just looking at it.

Comment: @PatrickHofman I need to go much far yet need to learn much but thanks to guys like you I can learn

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The second parameter for `Parallel.For` is the "to" (exclusive) value, not the "number of repetitions":

```
public static ParallelLoopResult For(
    int fromInclusive,
    int toExclusive,
    Action<int> body
)
```

In your code that means that after the first iteration, the from will be equal or larger than the to value.

So your code should be:

```
Parallel.For(i, i + 10, x => {
   //HttpRequest

});
```

Comment: Thank you so much. You save my time.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that you have problems with *ranges*; depending on what you want it's either

```
 for (int i = 0; i < UrlList.Count; i++) {
   // at 0th, 10th, 20th ... N * 10 ... position 
   if (i % 10 == 0) {
     // Control session: 
     // HttpRequest ...
   }
 }
```

or

```
 int step = 10;

 for (int i = 0; i < UrlList.Count; ++i) {
   // Control session can appear at any moment, indepent on i 
   if (control.SessionControl(false, 0)) {
     // When we at i-th postion we want 10 loops more: i + step
     // not from i to step
     Parallel.For(i, i + step, x => {
      //HttpRequest
     });

     i += (step - 1);
   }
 }
```